# Model and Query data in Firestore to get items in directories

Tags: firebase, model, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I want to model data in firestore to get **items** in **directories** shared by several **users** (folders are secured with security rules).

### My current model is as follows:

- */folders/{folder}/folders/{subfolder}*
- */folders/{folder}/items/{item}*
- */folders/{folder}/folders/{subfolder}/items/{item}*

A user can access several folders and if he accesses the root folder he can also access the subfolders. He can also access subfolders (if he has permission) and his access to the root folder is restricted.

The idea is that the system can list all the items that the user can access.

Is there a way without having to make a query for each folder?

---

If I make a query for each folder I would have a query for each root and for each subfolder. It would be many queries

Duplicating the access roles of the folders in the items could be an option but with a big problem when the permissions are modified

> The directory can only have up to two depth levels (root and
>   subfolders).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you building some kind of file system? Does the user has access to all items inside the folders?

Comment: What I am trying to archive are events. These events are going to be grouped in these folders.
It would be a kind of file system.
While users can access the folder they can access all these events

Answer (score 0):

You could have a document per user where you can write every folder id the user can access. Then you could query only these folders.

And if you have a lot of events the users can access i would recommend to show a folder structure to the user like in a file system. So you could save a lot of unnecessary reads for documents the user does not need.

Comment: The problem with that is that I need to make a query for each folder, and that would raise costs. I had thought the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57797821/can-i-query-sub-collections-in-a-collection-group
That's possible?