# Can I query sub collections in a collection group?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

In my app I have one collection group "Folder" with one sub collection "Item". Can I query the "items" through an attribute of the collection group (folder)?

For example: get all the items belonging to a folder that the user has access

My **structure** is something like this:

***folders***/{folderId}/**items**/{itemId}

***folders***/{folderId}/**folders**/{folderId}/**items**/{itemId}

**Folder**
name: "mock"
roles: [user1:"owner", user2:"admin"]

Folder is a collection group where has user roles in a Map. The idea is to get the items in the folders where the user has an assigned role.

More info: [Model and Query data in Firestore to get items in directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799381/model-and-query-data-in-firestore-to-get-items-in-directories)

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data that you want to get.

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, I already added it

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add a screenshot of it.